# iOS - Adding more Emoji Icons/Images

Tags: ios, keyboard, settings, emoji

I created an iOS application for emoji icons. The app works good to display the emoji icons/images.
I want to add an option to add all my emoji icons to the keyboard (as it happens with Emoji application).
How can add an option in settings to add my emoji icons to the keyboard.

Comment: You can't. Apple does not provide any public API that allows you to make any changes of any kind to any of the system keyboards. And custom keyboard can only be used in your own app.

Comment: There are some apps already in app store where its able to add more emoji icons. So, are those icons not added to keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can only enable Emoji Keyboard, but they cannot add more images to the keyboard.